# Special characters from my language are not correct when compiled with pdfLatex

Tags: formatting, symbols

I have difficulties while using special symbols from my language such as š, č, ť.
I use this statement in my document:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech,british,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
š č ť ž ý á í é ä ú ô ň ď ľ
\end{document}
```

The output file looks all right (exactly the same characters as above), however when I copy the text from the output pdf file and paste it to any text editor, I see only following:

š c t ž ý á í é ä ú ô n d l

So a part of symbols is incorrect in the output.

I use pdfLatex for the compression. When I use Latex+dvips+ps2pdf, everything is allright. However I need to use pdfLatex for various reasons and I believe that the solution must be simple.

Note that I use `\usepackage{lmodern}`. Without that the copied and pasted output would be totally broken (both with Latex and pdfLatex compression it would be ² £ ´ º ý á í é ä ú ô ¬ ¤ ©).

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Works for me with pdfLaTeX when I copy and paste in SumatraPDF (on Win 10), but not with Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cmap` package *before* `fontenc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 \begin{document}
  %š č ť ž ý á í é ä ú ô ň ď ľ
  \Huge

 Law \v{s}hould be made stri\u{c} 
    \'{t}.  Th\"{o}se Lawyers who
 participated i\u{n} the ri\v{o}t 
should n\^{o}t be allowed to practice
 for a year or two. 

 \end{document}
```

Comment: That shouldn’t make any differenceL the issue is with the non-Unicode font encodings.